# Burninate the [interpeter] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just encountered the [interpeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpeter) tag. I'm not a native speaker, so I queried Google Translate in order to find any sensible translation for "interpeter", but it just offers to correct the word to "interpreter", which convinces me of the non-existence of that word.

Can we remove the [interpeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpeter) tag, please? I know it's a minor issue but we're on the endless road to perfection, right?

Comment: There are only six questions. Just edit them well, and be done with it.

Comment: @Deduplicator Seems like a reasonable suggestion but wouldn't that still open the possibility of more questions with this wrong tag? If burnination was a big deal I wouldn't bother anybody with this but it isn't, is it?

Comment: ...? Six questions are few enough for one person alone even without meta-discussion, if he is sure.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, of course, I get that, but is the tag automatically removed when no question's tagged with it? NOTE: I just came across [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags). Pretty much answers my question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [interpeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpeter) is no more, may he rest in peace.

[image: Trogdor]

Notes: [scripting-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripting-language) should probably be synonymized to [scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripting).